# link DB2 AS/400 (system i) and DB2 AIX

Tags: db2

I have two different database in DB2, a in DB2 AS400 and other in DB2 AIX, is possible link this database, similar to link by Oracle?

Thank you in advance.

erva.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely possible to define a nickname in DB2 on AIX that allows you to access DB2 on iSeries.

The software required depends on the version and edition of DB2 you have on your AIX server, though.